# How do I format the date in a foreign language?

Tags: date

I currently have the task of building an EE site in Chinese. All is going well so far, but I have a problem trying to get the date shown in chinese. Anyone have a solution to this?

I'm just using the following standard date code at the moment:

```
{current_time format="%l %j%S %F, %Y"}
```

Comment: You know, I think if you set the locale on your server it might just do it automatically. Try adding [setlocale](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php) to your index.php file.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Firstly - you need to check that your server has Chinese Encoding installed - if it does, then what you need is the plugin that I wrote many years ago:

[Date/Time Language Converter](http://www.madebyhippo.com/addons)

You can then use this plugin to wrap your date/time value and specify the language and it'll format it in the appropriate language.

Comment: Thanks for this Carl. I've got the plugin working, although I had to set the format to the following: {current_time format="%U"} which creates a unix timestamp for the plugin to convert from.

Answer (score 2):

You can also just install the Chinese language pack.  This will also convert the CP to Chinese, but you can set a language preference per user to override it.

Answer (score 1):

What format do you need to output?

So I'm not a Chinese speaker, so will very happily defer to anyone who knows more than me, but as I understand it the convention is to format the date "Year Month Day", with each value followed by the relevant character 年 (nián) for year, 月 (yuè) for month, and 日 (rì) for day. Assuming that you are using a utf-8 charset can you not just do: `{current_time  format="%y年 %m月 %d日"}`

If you need to output the day of the the week or a more complex format though it looks like you might be best off with @madebyhippo's plugin, which looks super flexible.

Comment: Thanks Tom - I've gone with @madebyhippo's plugin and it's working so far.